# ggplot2, line types mismatched with specified in aes mapping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I specify linetype for each line, turns out solid becomes dotted, dotted becomes solid. I tried using solid, dashed and dotted, but still can't figure out what's the order of linetypes displayed in plot. Below is code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

p = ggplot(data = msleep, aes(x = log(bodywt), y = sleep_total)) + 
  geom_point() + #' This time we will vary the feeding groups by shapes instead of colors
  geom_smooth(method='lm')

gg_data <- ggplot_build(p)


sleepplot2 = ggplot(data = msleep, aes(x = log(bodywt), y = sleep_total)) + 
  geom_point(shape=4, size=3, color='blue') + #' This time we will vary the feeding groups by shapes instead of colors
  geom_text(aes(label=name), nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = 1) +
  labs(x = "Log body weight (Kg)", y = "Time asleep (hrs/day)") +
  ggtitle('Housing 1990-2007') +
  geom_line(color='red', data = gg_data$data[[2]], mapping=aes(x = x, y = ymin, linetype='solid'), size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(color='red',data = msleep, mapping=aes(x = log(bodywt), y = sleep_total, linetype='dotted'), method='lm', se = FALSE, size=0.5) +
  geom_line(color='red', data = gg_data$data[[2]], mapping=aes(x = x, y = ymax, linetype='solid'), size = 0.5) +
  scale_linetype_manual('', values = c("solid","dotted"),labels=c("Fit: y=0.3*x", "95% conf. bounds"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the following code: (which is the same as your code without using the `ggtheme` package)

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = msleep, aes(x = log(bodywt), y = sleep_total)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')

ggplot(data = msleep, aes(x = log(bodywt), y = sleep_total)) + 
  geom_point(shape=4, size=3, color='blue') +
  geom_text(aes(label=name), nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = 1) +
  labs(x = "Log body weight (Kg)", y = "Time asleep (hrs/day)") +
  ggtitle('Housing 1990-2007') +
  geom_line(color='red', data = gg_data$data[[2]], mapping=aes(x = x, y = ymin, linetype='solid'), size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(color='red',data = msleep, mapping=aes(x = log(bodywt), y = sleep_total, linetype='dotted'), method='lm', se = FALSE, size=0.5) +
  geom_line(color='red', data = gg_data$data[[2]], mapping=aes(x = x, y = ymax, linetype='solid'), size = 0.5) +
  scale_linetype_manual('', values = c("dotted","solid"),labels=c("Fit: y=0.3*x", "95% conf. bounds"))
```

Gives us the following plot:

[image: plot needed]

And the legend as well as the three lines on the plot seem to be agreeing with what the plot you wanted to achieve.

Comment: have you noticed that, in your figure, dotted line should be solid line, solid line should be dotted line?  check aes setting

Comment: Sorry, check the edited answer. I simply changed the order of `"solid"` and `"dotted"` in the last line, and we got the desired plot. I'm not sure why the mismatch was happening. Checking the documentation of `ggplot2` I didn't find anything related to this, but it seems that the last line overrides the previous settings, (because if I remove the last line then the linetypes would again be matched wrong, despite the aes settings)

Comment: Thanks, I think we've found a bug of ggplot2

Comment: @zouhx Can you link to me the documentation you found to code the  scale_linetype_manual line? Thanks

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.2.1/topics/scale_manual  You want to check source code?